# insert statement difficulty

Tags: mysql, netbeans-7

this is where I am getting my info from, and when I choose the address it fills in all the info
but the problem starts when I try to add a renter to the renter table after I have deleted a renter. this table no longer shows columns with all addressIDs so I am trying to insert the AddressID as well from the property table.I hope this makes sense
I cant insert pictures yet, but here is what it looks like when i chose a property,  [rentals](http://etraci.com/2ndsemester/Capture.jpg)

---

```
if ( ( evt.getStateChange() == java.awt.event.ItemEvent.SELECTED ) &&
     ( PropertyComboBox.getSelectedIndex() != 0 ) )
            {
                Address = ( String ) PropertyComboBox.getSelectedItem();


     try {
  myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(
            "SELECT Property.Address,Property.AddressID,Property.RentAmt, Renter.RenterID, Renter.AddressID, Renter.FirstName, Renter.LastName, Renter.CellPhone, Renter.DepositPaid,Renter.DepositAmtPaid " +
             "FROM Property, Renter " +
"WHERE Property.Address = '" + Address + "'" +  "AND Renter.AddressID = Property.AddressID" );


if (myResultSet.next())
            {
                renterID = (myResultSet.getString("Renter.RenterID"));
                addressID = (myResultSet.getString("Property.AddressID"));


        txtRentAmt.setText(myResultSet.getString("Property.RentAmt"));
        txtShowAddressID.setText(myResultSet.getString("Property.AddressID"));

        txtShowRenterID.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.RenterID"));

        txtFirstName.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.FirstName"));
    txtLastName.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.LastName"));
        txtCellPhone.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.CellPhone"));
    txtDepositPaid.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.DepositPaid"));
        txtDepositAmtPaid.setText(myResultSet.getString("Renter.DepositAmtPaid"));


        if(myResultSet.getString("Renter.DepositPaid") == ("Y"))
          {
           txtDepositPaid.setText("Y");
          }

                else
                {
                    txtDepositPaid.setText("N");
                }
            }
        }
```

---

> can someone help me with this ?  I am trying to insert a new renter
>   from a netbeans jform into my database.  The AddressID
>   (PK,auto-increment ) from the property table should automatically
>   insert into the renter table  AddressID (FK, auto-increment(so I
>   thought)
>
> It will insert if I use this statement but then the addressID shows as
>   NULL, not the AddressID from the property table, which I need. Ive
>   been working on this since Saturday. UGH Please help! very simple, yet
>   I cannot figure it out
>
> ```
>  ls_query = "INSERT INTO Renter  (FirstName,LastName,CellPhone,DepositPaid,DepositAmtPaid)" 
>                     + " VALUES (" + addressID + ",'" 
>                     + addFirstName + "','" 
>                     + addLastName + "','" 
>                     + addCellPhone + "','" 
>                     + addDepositPaid + "'," 
>                     + addDepositAmtPaid + ")" + " WHERE Property.AddressID = " + addressID ;
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT plus WHERE? i guess you need UPDATE, not INSERT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

EDIT: it's not clear, you are mixing in insert in one table with a where in another table?, just do "INSERT ... (fields) VALUES (values)" without WHERE and specify all addressID on fields.

Comment: it cant be update, ive tried. It's because when I delete a renter it actually deletes the whole record so then I need to insert any given propertyID into the information again in the renter table.

Comment: propertyID? please, explain your problem a little better, it's not clear right now

Comment: Im sorry, I meant AddressID.

Comment: ok ill try this, I think I have been looking to hard for answers on the internet. trust me I have tried so many different ways...thanks so much for answering so fast, I do appreciate it. Obviously I'm a newbie and have much to learn.

Comment: I couldnt get it to work. but thanks... I imagine I will figure it out eventually...

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify `AddressID` in the field list.

```
...INTO Renter (AddressID, FirstName...
```

Assuming that you specify all columns in the table, you can omit the field list.

You may also be more comfortable with the [`INSERT ... SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) syntax.